# svg to png not working, suspect svg element differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Im having trouble figuring out why two different svg's would cause my javascript to work in one instance, but not in the other. I have only swapped out the svg elements in both examples, one works, one does not. Here is the code in two jsFiddles. The working example I got from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/8187844).

Ultimately, my goal is to save the current svg element of the floor plan, and insert the converted png as an inline img inside a rich text area. As if you took a cropped screenshot of the floor plan, and pasted it into a rich text area like you see in helpdesk sites. Im just having trouble converting to png.

Working: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dogbyte/a0bcf1kk/)

Not Working: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dogbyte/jdh0y4c2/4/)

Here is the js, i cant add the svg code or it will put me over the character limit of Stackoverflow.

```
    var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('#svg2'));

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([svgString], {
  type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.querySelector('#png-container').innerHTML = '<img src="' + png + '"/>';
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
};
img.src = url;
```

Edit:

I have since settled on this code omitting the png/canvas conversions, and trying to place the serialized string of the svg, directly to the rich text area, but it gets an error in IE, Non-default namespace declarations must not have an empty URI. Line: 1, column142

```
var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('#svg2'));

var img = new Image();

var url = "data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, "+encodeURIComponent(svgString); 
img.onload = function() {

    document.querySelector('.ze_body').innerHTML = '<img src="'+url+'"/>';

};
img.src = url;
```

Also i think it would help if i showed more of the structure of how this rich text area currently sits. This is not our doing, its a product we use, and im just trying to get maps to paste into the description area so it can live with the ticket. Only access we have is js triggered from rules in the form. 
[Screenshot of ze_body element as it stands in the DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0KYy.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from your namespace declaration :

Change

```
xmlns:NS1="" NS1:xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:NS2="" NS2:xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:NS3="" NS3:xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
```

to

```
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
```

and it [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/jdh0y4c2/5/).

*You can read about namespace declaration [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course).*

Comment: Thank you very much, i see folks cleaning up the namespace all the time in videos, but I made these svgs with inkscape, and even saving them Optimized, it still leaves a lot of cleaning up to do. I have more reading to do looks like, thanks again.

Comment: Do you have any idea why your Jsfiddle will not work in IE? I originally tried this in Chrome, but i need this to work in IE 11 as well. I cant get any errors in the console, but the png img is definitely not printing to screen.

Comment: Yes, IE is very limited for this task. Apparently it doesn't support the declaration of any namespace… If you remove them all, you'll be able to draw to canvas : http://jsfiddle.net/jdh0y4c2/9/. But then, it will taint the canvas, making it  unable to deliver its `dataURL` or `imageData` (apparently IE dev thought that svg can include scripts so the canvas CORS should apply to any svg image drawn into canvas. I don't know any workaround, except the one asking your IE user to right click the svg or the canvas, `save image as...` but it won't be usefull in your case...

Comment: actually have you tried to put the `<img>` which displays the svg instead of converting it to png?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last comment, im not sure i follow. do you mean adding the src location to the svg, inside the img tag?

Comment: Well, `var img `is an `<img>` element. In order to convert it to png, you passed a blobURL containing your svg file, or I showed you that you can actually simply pass the `encodeURIComponent(svg.outerHTML)` as src of this image. So instead of drawing it to the canvas, maybe you can just append this `var img`, which now displays the svg, to your "rich text area", as a callback for IE.

Comment: Ah ok... man im learning so much from this. So something like this is what you were wondering? [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdh0y4c2/9/)

Comment: I guess my last example still will not work in IE will it? Since it will still get the non-default namespace error in IE as the svg gets serialized. So i guess i really didnt solve anything with trading out the png with the url containing the encoded URI.

Comment: found [this](http://tinyurl.com/nzsvp9b) on msdn forums. about the source code in the svg getting corrupted from IE's use of the xmlserializer.. this was over a year ago though. i hope there is a work around, or another way to parse the html of the svg, someone on there suggested that maybe nodeiterator may work to not corrupt the namespaces in the svg?

Comment: Kaiido i really do appreciate what you've offered, but now im having second thoughts on my choice as to where to place the pasted img, probably due to my lack of understanding/expertise. the ze_body has a select tag that it looks like it uses for inline images, so i dont know if its usable in the same way we've been trying to use ze_body [see screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/v2UwaVI.png)

Comment: @Dogbyte didn't though of `nodeIterator`, maybe a good catch? Could be inserted in the `img.onerror` if it does work. For the inclusion of inline images, I don't think it will make such a difference for the client if you convert it to png or not. What I see from your screenshot is that it will be nested in an iframe. If the document displayed in the iframe is on the same domain as the main document, you can access it via `yourIframeElement.contentDocument.querySelector('.ze_body')`.

Comment: yes i just used the insert image button (instead of clipboard paste) to see how it inserts the screenshot into the iframe. [look here](http://i.imgur.com/leMti4Y.png) I may be trying to programmatically insert the image to the description area in the most difficult way due to my inexperience... still looking though.

Comment: its doing a post back to the server, then a get to fill the src of the inline img. [see here](http://i.imgur.com/Uc6yEz3.png)  so I may need to post a separate question, i have the feeling im gonna get moderated if we keep going like this.