# SVG to canvas using XPCOM

Tags: canvas, svg, firefox-addon-sdk, xul, xpcom

I'm trying to render an `svg` file in a `canvas` by just using `xpcom` (no gui). For this purpose I'm running the following javascript code using `xpcshell` (firefox-sdk):

```
const Cc = Components.classes;
var data = '<html><img src="test.svg"/></html>'

var parser = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/domparser;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMParser);
var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
var x = doc.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

var canvas = Cc["@mozilla.org/xul/xul-document;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMDocument).implementation.createDocument("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "html", null).createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "canvas");
canvas.setAttribute("height", 32);
canvas.setAttribute("width", 32);

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(x, 0, 0);
```

But I get the folling error:

```
JavaScript error: test_decode_html.js, line 112: NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:
```

line 112: `context.drawImage(x, 0, 0);`

What is wrong with my code? Alternatively, is there another way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: does test.svg have height and width attributes on the root SVG element. If it does are those values non-percentages?

Comment: So you're saying this can't be done for any valid SVG? I just downloaded a random svg with a tiger on it.

Comment: There are some restrictions (bugs if you like) which may one day be fixed.

Comment: From tests (don't know the specs about it maybe @RobertLongson you could help me find it btw ?), svg rendered in `<img>` tags must have an absolute `height`and `width` property/attribute set, to be drawn onto a canvas. External data references inside the svg won't be loaded by the `<img>`, these should be included in the document directly. Some custom NameSpaces declarations will make the loading to fail. Also, and maybe the most plausible issue in your case, you are not waiting for the `<img>` has loaded before you draw it on the canvas. But I don't know xpcom at all, so maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: you can have custom namespaces provided you declare them. The rest is pretty much spot on.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes you can, but some will fail, at least in IE, where namespaces with empty uri aren't allowed. Also, it seems that some softs like Inkscape does provide invalid namespace declarations, that will fail in all browsers once passed into an `<img>` element [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546006/svg-to-png-not-working-suspect-svg-element-differences/31556108)

Comment: @Kaiido IE does not support XPCOM, so the OP can't be targeting that.

Comment: @RobertLongson yep but the question I linked had issues on all browsers (FF included)