# How to convert svg to image in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, base64

I have an `svg` element which I have to convert it to `image`.

```
var svg = this.panelContent.nativeElement.querySelector('svg');
var img = new Image();
// get svg data
var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);

// make it base64
var svg64 = btoa(xml);
var b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';

// prepend a "header"
var image64 = b64Start + svg64;
// set it as the source of the img element
img.src = image64;
```

This is working perfectly in chrome browser but in `IE11` I receive following error:

> XML5661: Non-default namespace declarations must not have an empty
>   URI.

I spend over 1 day for this and I didn't find one solution yet.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546006/svg-to-png-not-working-suspect-svg-element-differences

Comment: @Lain, I already tried your sugestion.

Comment: Any external resources (xlink, images)? Any sample SVG?